# WSO2 ESB No Response after POST request

Tags: api, post, wso2, esb

I am using WSO2 ESB to send a POST request to a Rest API of mine. 
actually, the API returns a 201 status with some data.
The API itself using POSTMAN works perfectly, but a 202 accepted response is return using the ESB link 
here's my implementation: 
the POST API Link:
http://mysite/sites/4/floors/4/pois/12/prelock

My ESB API :

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/sites/{siteId}/floors/{floorId}/pois/{poiId}/prelock">
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
        <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="Status" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="NodeRedPrelock"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

endpoint :

```
<endpoint name="NodeRedPrelock" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<http method="post" uri-template="http://mysite/sites/{uri.var.siteId}/floors/{uri.var.floorId}/pois/{uri.var.poiId}/prelock"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the http method .Can you try with this

```
    <endpoint name="NodeRedPrelock" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <http trace="disable" uri-template="http://169.46.25.33:1880/sites/{uri.var.siteId}/floors/{uri.var.floorId}/pois/{uri.var.poiId}/prelock"/>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you check your sequence in Carbon interface?

Some times when you deploy car to esb carbon remove endpoint from "send" tag.

Or it's seems as problem in endpoint. You can try resave endpoint in interface. Sometimes I have problem after deploy car file and endpoint don't work until make  save by hand.

Comment: Actually, that was the problem, I was modifying on the graphic interface but the XML file was not changing, therefore when I tried Mr Basanagouda's solution it didn't work :D thank you for your help